# How to add an mutable array of objects to another object in swift (array of classes)

Tags: swift

If I have to swift classes.

```
class Route : NSObject {
    var routeNo: String!
    var routeName: String!
}
```

and

```
class Stop : NSObject {
    var stopName: String!
    var routes: [Route]!
}
```

In my ViewController, I want to be able to add any number of routes for a stop.

```
var route1 = Route()
route1.routeNo = "1"
route1.routeName = "Direction for route 1"

var route2 = Route()
route2.routeNo = "2"
route2.routeName = "Direction for route 2"

// now, create a Stop object and add the two routes
var stop = Stop()
stop.stopName = "5th Avenue/3rd Street"
stop.routes.append(route1)
stop.routes.append(route2)
```

This unfortunately does not work. It compiles fine but get this error at run time:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value at the line stop.routes.append(route1).

I have absolutely no clue what this means. I tried all sort of condition checks but no luck.

What is the solution to be able to add any number of instances of Route the the Stop object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app crashes because you didn't initialise your routes array.

This should fix the problem:

```
class Stop : NSObject {
    var stopName: String!
    var routes: [Route] = []
}
```